# Scala/Spark Select Column very slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala/spark (about a week now)

The following code is being run on my 8 core laptop, 64bit, Win10
The dataframe has 1700 rows.
ONE select takes over ten seconds.

Watching the console shows the main hang is at this point:

> 17/09/02 12:23:46 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with:

*The Code*

```
{

    val major:String =name.substring(0,name.indexOf("_SCORE"))+"_idx1"
    println(major)
    val majors = dfMergedDroppedDeleted
      .select(col(major))
      .collect().toSeq
    println(s"got majors ${majors.size}")
}
```

This should  take milliseconds (based on experience with hibernate,r,mysql etc)
I am assuming there is something wrong with my configuration of spark?

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

*The full console output up to the hang is as follows:*

> 1637_1636_1716_idx1
>
> 1637_1636_1716_idx2
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 765
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 763
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_51_piece0 on 192.168.0.13:62246 in memory (size: 113.7 KB, free: 901.6 MB)
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 761
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 764
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 762
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 766
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_50_piece0 on 192.168.0.13:62246 in memory (size: 20.7 KB, free: 901.6 MB)
>
> 17/09/02 12:23:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with:

Comment: Spark is not built for the same purposes as a database like MySQL. Where are you running this? In spark shell or submit? How many files and how many partitions? What code are you running before this?

Comment: I'm running currently as a junit test. One datafile imported from csv. Prior to this, there have been a number of dataframe transformation where columns have been merged with withColumn(). It's a lot of code that I did not believe was relevant to this question as I now have a single dataframe of about 1000 variables and 1700 rows

Comment: NOTE: This is part of a data cleaning operation. The sort of thing I typically do in R.

Comment: the time consuming part is not select. select is distributed in nature and would be executed in every local data in executors. The time consuming part is the collect. Collect function collects all the data in the driver node. And that takes a lot of time. Thats why collect is always recommended not to be used and if necessary to use it the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the dataframe in cache makes a big difference.

```
val dfMergedDroppedDeletedCached:DataFrame=dfMergedDroppedDeleted.cache()
```

However, the caching process itself is slow, so this only pays off if you are performing multiple operations

**UPDATE**
Credit Ramesh Maharjan to who wrote in a comment:

> the time consuming part is not select. select is distributed in nature and would be executed in every local data in executors. The time consuming part is the collect. Collect function collects all the data in the driver node. And that takes a lot of time. Thats why collect is always recommended not to be used and if necessary to use it the minimum.

I have changed the query to be as follows:

```
          val majorstr:String = dfMergedDroppedDeletedCached.filter(dfMergedDroppedDeletedCached(major).isNotNull)
            .select(col(major))
            .limit(1)
            .first().getString(0)
```

Not exactly Oracle speeds but much faster than using collect

Comment: You also deserve the rep. If you want to repost the answer under your name, I will happily delete mine. I don't want to "steal" rep, just want to be sure the answer is out there, as this has not been discussed on the internet before, to my knowledge

Comment: let the answer be as it is. You have written it perfectly. :)